# ASP.NET_SessionId - ¿Qué puedo hacer para que al abrir un url por segunda vez el navegador envíe la cookie segura?

Tags: asp.net, https, cookies

Tengo una aplicación web que está instalada en algunos servidores locales (accedida en una red local, solo http) y en servidores externos (accedidos por Internet, solo https).

Al iniciar una nueva sesión establezco la cookie `asp.net_sessionid` como segura si la conexión es segura (VB, .NET Framework 4.6.2):

```
Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 

  If Request.IsSecureConnection Then 
    Me.Response.Cookies("ASP.NET_SessionId").Secure = True
  End If

End Sub
```

(Respuesta de [How to secure the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978667/how-to-secure-the-asp-net-sessionid-cookie))

**Cuando la conexión es segura (https)**: si el usuario se loguea puede trabajar normalmente (usualmente trabaja con varias pantallas emergentes); pero si el usuario abre una nueva pestaña y escribe el url de la aplicación, o hace clic en un bookmark a la misma (ver nota más abajo), se genera una nueva Cookie `asp.net_sessionid`, lo que causa que la sesión que tenía abierta se cierre automáticamente; si esto ocurre el usuario debe volver a loguearse: este es el *error*.

El problema está en que el navegador no envía la cookie segura cuando solicita (GET) la pantalla de loggin en una nueva pestaña: Asp.Net genera un nuevo sessionid, cerrando la sesión anterior.

**Cuando la conexión no es segura (http)**: la cookie tampoco será segura. En este caso la cookie *si es enviada* junto con la petición GET al abrir la segunda pestaña; con esto la primera sesión se mantiene abierta: este es el comportamiento esperado.

Por lo que sé sobre el funcionamiento de el flag `secure` de las cookies, la cookie debería enviarse en ambos casos.

Mi pregunta:

#### ¿Qué puedo hacer para que al abrir la pantalla de loggin el navegador envíe la cookie segura que ya está establecida?

**NOTA:** Mi aplicación implementa `SessionStateStoreProviderBase` para admitir múltiples sesiones en un mismo navegador; nuestros usuarios esperan esta característica ya que podían hacer lo mismo en la aplicación de escritorio que nosotros reemplazamos con nuestra aplicación web. El manejo de sesión ha funcionado correctamente por 8 años bajo http, y 2 bajo https. El problema solo ocurre cuando establezco como segura la cookie `asp.net_sessionid` (lo cual solo hago bajo https).